# rubymine proxy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Traté de instalar una gema en `rubymine` y obtuve el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
>    Unable to download data from https rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Luego configuré el `proxy` así:

```
set http_proxy=http://user:pass@serv:port
```

y tuve el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Net::HTTPServerException)
>   407 "Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )"

¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: Hola hernan, este sito es para hacer preguntas en español. Por favor traduce la pregunta o formulala en el sitio en ingles.

Comment: ya fue traducida la pregunta. gracias

Comment: @hernan Dice que no tenés acceso en el proxy. ¿Seguro que el usuario y clave están bien?

Comment: si, el usuario es correcto. puede ser que desde la empresa no me den los privilegios que necesito?

Comment: @hernan Podés probar descargar el archivo directamente cuando estés en la empresa... Con la información que diste, la pregunta es demasiado amplia